# DeadLock in mysql using Spring TransactionTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I'm using spring transationTemplate , and run some queries by doInTransaction method.
I got exception about deadLock, on 2 queries that executed sequentially into the transaction.

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE(A,B,C) VALUES ('AAA','BBB','CCC');

UPDATE  TABLE SET PRICE = null  WHERE A='AAA' AND B='BBB';
```

How is it possible? and what is the solution?